# JavaScript function to re-arrange date format

Tags: javascript, function, date, format

I'm working on some analytics, using Google Tag Manager.

We have a datalayer on the site, one of the value's is a date in format DDMMYYYY.

For a media tag I need to change this date to YYYY-MM-DD.

I'm trying something like this as an example: but I can't get it to work.
*I am a total novice with Javascript*

```
(function(){
var d = {{Departure_Date}}
var u = {{Departure_Date}}.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/,'$3$2$1')
return u

})()
```

Here {{Departure_Date}} is a variable that access the dataLayer and pulls out the original date format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Note that `05122014.replace(...)` is not valid code ;)

Answer (score 0):

[**assuming `{{Departure_Date}}` is a string, like `'04032003'`**]

Almost there. Try `[ddmmyyyy].replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/, '$3-$2-$1')`. Alternatively, you can slice up the ddmmyyyy string (see snippet)

```js
var res = document.querySelector('#result');

res.innerHTML = 'input: 20052014, output: ' + 
                '20052015'.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/, '$3-$2-$1');

// Alternative:
var inp = '18072013';
res.innerHTML += '<br>input: 18072013, output: ' + 
                 [inp.slice(4), inp.slice(2,4), inp.slice(0,2)].join('-');
```

```html
<div id="result"><div>
```

Comment: I notice you have quotes around the date value. Do we have evidence that OP's code features such quotes? ;)

Comment: Given the format DDMMYYYY I presumed a string value (e.g. 02021993). The method `replace` would be another indication `{{Departure_Date}}` is a string.

Comment: I agree with you, but let's say this were PHP and I had `<?php echo "02021993"; ?>.replace(...)` - even though I have a string in PHP, the rendered JavaScript doesn't get the quotes.

Comment: Well, let the OP decide. He/she's using angular.js I think, I didn't see a server scripting tag in the question

Comment: Yeah, the lack of a server scripting tag is making it difficult to judge, but "lack of quotes around injected value" is the biggest cause of this kind of problem, so that's why I bring it up

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your time in answering my question.  I ended up using substring of the values and then just moving them around.